# Display a hint that search used a tag that doesn't exist

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, tag-search

When doing a search and using a tag in the search, there's nothing in the UI that hints that the tag used does not exist. After doing the search, the suggestions don't mention checking the tag(s) used. They only mention to check the keywords.

I did a search using [sqlserver] when the correct one is [sql-server].

Comment: I suspect if you had typed slower, you'd have realized there was tags which started with "sql", which may have given you what you were looking for ... to which I'd say, the logic/hint you are asking for is already in the system. I don't assume what I'm asking for has never been asked or tagged before. I will go back several times to see if I missed something, making what I'm typing into the tag box smaller until something pops which might match. Seems to work fairly well.

Comment: Are you talking about when I am in the tags page? I am talking about when I am in the search box and I enter a tag between square brackets. There's no autocomplete or hints there at all.

Comment: I am also asking for enhancements after the form is submitted regardless of how the UI works while entering keywords in the search box. Display more information in the suggestions area.

Comment: Gotcha. You're right, it doesn't give you any kind of hint when in the search input.